# Error on "findViewById(R.id.video)"

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-activity, android-resources

please help me as i'm hell stuck in an idiot error :( ..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"/>
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is xml which i think is correct.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    VideoView videoview;
    Button button;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //videoview=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video);
        //button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);


    }
```

and that one is java file..im getting an error when im getting videoview and button through their id's. error is "video cannot be resolved or is not a field"

please tell me if you know the solution
thankyou

Comment: runtime error or compile time error?

Comment: Could you give us a little more information like logcat?

Comment: I run your code,it worked. please post your imports and logcat

Comment: Stefano,its compile time error

Comment: Did you build and clean the project?

Comment: @MHP dont tell me really ? :o then why im getting error :(

Comment: @StefanoVuerich no.leme do it

Comment: Alwayssssssssssss build your project when you get this kind of error!!!

Comment: ohh got it :)) really thankful to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build and clean the project will solve your problem